# usage of article in front of 'leap year'

Tags: grammaticality

I have read  a sentence .
''The year with an extra day is called leap year.''
I wonder why the writer did not use 'article'' in front of leap year.
Please explain it to me.

Comment: Try reading this out loud: "_The year with an extra day is called the leap year_". Doesn't it sound redundant? Don't you think that the extra _'the'_ sounds unnecessary ?

Comment: Can we obmit   'article' for sound?

Comment: Can you show us where you found this?  It sounds wrong to me without an article.

Comment: This sentence should not start with **The**, unless you are speaking about a specific year. _The year I was born in was a leap year_.  IMO this sentence should be written: _A year with an extra day is called a leap year._

Comment: Your phrase could refer to any leap year, not a specific one. But suppose you planned to go on a luxury vacation in 2016, since you like to do special things on leap years. Then, "This is *the leap year* I have been waiting for."